# motherboard featuring intel iris 540 or 550 or 580

Tags: motherboard

## Reason

I wanted to wait for buying this hardware upgrade. However, the motherboard of my computer stopped to work this morning, so the need become more urgent *(I'm writing this with my tablet)*.

## Rules

- The motherboard need to be atx compatible. It should feature at least 1 pcie x16 slot and at least a mini pci one.
- I don't care about core or Xeon. The whole price should be below 700€.
- The cpu should be at least a quad core one.
- The motherboard need to support hardware or fake raid 1.
- The delivery should be possible in France. *(many intel cpu models are not sold here)*
- Should not consume more than 250W.

## Update

I need to say for those gpu models that the available cpu sockets are [bga only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) *(no lga based models availaible yet)*. Except if I'm wrong.

So it means while I'm looking for a particular gpu model, the cpu+gpu+motherboard is sold as a single device which can't be ordered into separate parts *(the same way you don't buy a northbridge chipset without a motherboard)*.
This why I specify the requirements of both the cpu and the motherboard.

Comment: @Adam also finding an atx compatible motherboard with a bga socket seems unlikely.

Comment: As far as I know, a ATX compatible Skylake GT3/4/e SKU is not offered by Intel. Is there any reason that your requirements can not be met by a dedicated graphics chip such as the GT 730, or a Broadwell/Haswell socketed SKU?

Comment: @Alpha3031 I which to keep my previous 600W power supply for my new motherboard. I also wan to keep a pcie x16 for something which isn't a gpu. I want to get support for vulkan *(not sure vulkan will be supportted on broadwell)*. The motherboard manufacturer doesn't have to be intel.

Comment: So, what would you be using the extra x16 lanes for? And why have you ruled out the HD Graphics 530/520?

Comment: @Alpha3031 14 fps with hd graphics 530.

Comment: **What** are you doing that is performing unacceptably with HD 530 and acceptably with the Iris 540 or 550 or Iris Pro 580? And **what** are you doing that requires a full x16 lane PCIe connect? In short, **what will you be doing** on the hardware, and what is your budget? That is what I'll need to know to offer alternaltives, because, afaik, the product you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: I'm also voting to close this question as well as your other one because simply you have too many requirements (and you keep changing them). Please state *all* requirements in your question (for example *why* you can't use any other graphics  solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I found the socketed i5 5675C with Iris Pro 6200 (48 EU GT3e 128 MB L4) at [LDLC.com](http://www.ldlc.com/)

**CPU:** [Intel Core i5 5675C with Iris Pro 6200 iGP (€289.95 @ LDLC.com)](http://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00188815.html) [(Processor Specs @ Intel ARK)](http://ark.intel.com/products/88095/Intel-Core-i5-5675C-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz)

A multiplier unlocked quad core Intel CPU, it has 48 Gen 8 EUs, comparable to the Iris 540 and 550, and double the amount of L4 eDRAM. 65W TDP. Compatible with DDR3 RAM only.

**Motherboard:** [Gigabyte GA-Z97P-D3 (€89.95@ LDLC.com)](http://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00173785.html)

Z97 Express chipset, supports mulitplier overclocking, 2 x PCIe x16 slots, 2 x PCI. 6 X SATA 6 Gb/s with support for RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5, and RAID 10.

Second option @ [Sabmegastore](http://www.sabmegastore.com/commande.php?cat=mont&sm=4&p=1&mu=&comp=ORB000)

**CPU:** [Intel Core i5 6500 Quad core 3.2 GHz CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/88184/Intel-Core-i5-6500-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) 248.90 €

Is a quad core

**Motherboard:** [GIGABYTE Z170-HD3P](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5495) 142.90 €

Has 2 x PCIe x16 sots. One only uses x4 lanes though. Also has 2 x PCI and support for RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5, and RAID 10.

**GPU:** GIGABYTE GEFORCE GT 740

Much faster than Iris. 64W TDP, plus the 65 W from the CPU makes 129 W. 50% headroom gives 194W total consumption.

Assembly + 2 year warrenty is 69.00 €, otherwise buy the parts separately.

Comment: I already tried, Intel® HD Graphics 530, It’s half of I need. You can’t combine the remaining power of the cpu for getting what is missing on the graphic card.

Comment: @user2284570 That's why there's a GT740 included. It's much faster than the Iris 540/550. The motherboard has 2 x16 slots. One can be used for the GPU.

Comment: I won’t even be able to use things like Widi with such configuration *(the pcie x16 slot is taken no other card are supported by the controller)*.

Comment: @Alpha3031 To be fair the OP did mention in their question/comments on it that they have already populated the PCI-E x16 slot on their motherboard with a non-GPU card. However the OP does not seem to understand that there is no motherboard that meets their requirements as CPUs have the GPU integrated rather than on the motherboard.

Comment: @cybermonkey the need for an x16 slot was mentioned, but there has been no response as to whether the full 16 lanes are also required, or would 4 lanes for the secondary application would work. Alternately an AMD graphics card would able to operate with the x4 lanes in the second slot, leaving the full PCI for whatever OP already is using.

Comment: Also, I believe OP is looking for a embedded/factory soldered CPU, that comes soldered onto the relevant motherboard. To my knowledge, such a product does not exist retail, and can only be purchased by OEMs. Thus, the alternative is suggested, with **2** PCIe x16 slots.

Comment: @Alpha3031 : At the time I asked that question, I wasn’t sure if such Iris card would support VulKan.

Comment: @user2284570 Support for the Vulkan API is planned for Intel GPUs on Ivy Bridge and later on Linux for Mesa 11.3. For Nvidia GPUs since Kepler, Vulkan has been supported since driver version 355.00.27 on Linux and 356.39 on Windows. AMD supports Vulkan on Windows, but not Linux, for GCN 1.0 and later, after driver version 16.15.1009. I don't believe Vulkan will be supported for Windows with Intel Iris graphics. If Vulkan support is a necessity, Nvidia or Imagination Technologies Graphics chipsets will be best.

Comment: @Alpha3031 : Yeah, in fact due to the delay, I had to buy a cpu with Intel ʜᴅ 530. That’s how I could here tell it wasn’t enough for the games I intended to play *(and in fact the emulated ɢᴘᴜ provide more power than the hardware one)*. I will revert back to my plan to wait 1 year or 2 for Pascal with 3d memory *(before my motherboard failure)*. I was still curious to see if what I was really existed and it isn’t yet. As a student, this might be a better choice.